# How to retrieve photos from stolen phone

Tags: samsung, gmail

My phone got stolen last Friday. I never used to backup my photos or anything like that. Is there any possible way I can retrieve my photos?

Comment: Do you have a Google Account? Do you use Android Device Manager? We need way more information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you never backup your photos online, the only place those are stored is Phone storage which is stolen. So, the only way to retrieve those photos will be get back the phone with the storage. Otherwise, its a *No*